# How do you use the cursor for reading multiple files in database in python

Tags: python, mysql

In python how do you read multiple files from a mysql database using the cursor or loop one by one and store the output in a separate table?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221533/how-to-read-multiple-files-from-mysql-database-in-python.  Same question.  Different day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question (what are files?, what's your table structure?), but here goes a simple sample:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                           user="root",
                           password="merlin",
                           db="files")
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM files")
5L
>>> rows = cursor.fetchall()
>>> cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE destination (file varchar(255))")
0L
>>> for row in rows:
...   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO destination VALUES (%s)" % row[0])
...
1L
1L
1L
1L
1L
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, assuming you have created the table you want to move to, with descriptive names:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='username', db='dbname')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('select files from old_table where conditions=met')
>>> a = cur.fetchall()
>>> for item in a:
...     cur.execute('update new_table set new_field = %s' % item) # `item` should be tuple with one value, else use "(item,)" with comma
```